# How to return an entire column as an array using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch a column from a database and display the entire contents as an array. I have so far been able to fetch only one of the entries from the table. I understand that I am fetching only $row[0] which is why i am getting only 1 element. I have tried to fetch all elements but I have not succeeded yet. can someone please let me know how to do it correctly? I have attached my code below.

```
 <?php


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","raspberry","users");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "failled to connect:".mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    $sql = "SELECT `current` FROM `monitor` ORDER BY `Sno.`";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
    printf("%s\n",$row[0]);



    mysqli_close($con)

    ?>
```

Comment: Loop over the columns, e.g. `while(mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {...}`

Comment: `while($row=...) { echo $row[current]; }`

Answer (score 0):

PDO has a dedicated feature for your problem PDOStatement::[fetchColumn](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Answer (score -1):

So, from your question what I understand is- you want to fetch a database column and store this in a array which will make you to display the results.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","raspberry","users");



if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "failled to connect:".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql = "SELECT current FROM monitor ORDER BY Sno";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $arr2 = array();
     foreach ($row as $val) $arr2[] = $val;
     $arr[] = $arr2;
    }

$first_col = array_column($arr, 0);
print_r($first_col);

mysqli_close($con)
```

?>

i.e. if you have five entry to the database whose first column contains 
the values like 'current1', 'current2', 'current3', 'current3' and 'current4' the result of this code will be

Array
(
    [0] => current1
    [1] => current2
    [2] => current3
    [3] => current4
    [4] => current5
)

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I want to do. I tried to run the code with the changes that you made, It does not display anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, I edited your full code chunk and have written the complete script. Now if you have database table monitor with column current and sno, this will display the results from first column into an array.